# PHP Steam Inventory JSon Decoder

Tags: php, json, steam, steam-web-api

I've never worked with `json` before and I'm unsure how to fully. So essentially I need to get all the items in the `rgDescriptions` table, but I am honestly unsure how to.

So if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I've tried to look for documentation/tutorials on Json but can't seem to find advanced stuff.

Only stuff like `{"id":"2","instanceID":"8"}`

[Example of the json I want to decode](http://steamcommunity.com/id/nimahkiin/inventory/json/730/2)

Comment: you want to get `id` and `instanceId` from that json string is it??

Comment: I just posted a link of the json text I need to decode. I'm struggling because its such a big bit of text and so hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

use `json_desode()` to decode the json format.

```
$json = '{"id":"2","instanceID":"8"}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
print_r($decoded);// will print decoded format of your json
echo $decoded->id; // outputs => 2
echo $decoded->instanceID; // outputs => 8
```

Otuput:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 2
    [instanceID] => 8
)
```